# Kustomize installation failure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubectl, kustomize

I'm running into an issue installing Kustomize to a docker image based on Kubectl client version. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM alpine:3 AS base

 FROM base as build
 WORKDIR /downloads
 RUN apk add --update bash curl build-base go git jq --no-cache && \
     curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o kubectl && \
     chmod +x kubectl && \
     curl -o install_kustomize.sh "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh" && \
     chmod +x install_kustomize.sh && \
     ./install_kustomize.sh $(./kubectl version --output=json --client=true | jq -r '.kustomizeVersion[1:]')
     #chmod +x kustomize

FROM base as runtime
RUN apk add --update coreutils curl jq && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY --from=build /downloads/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
COPY --from=build /downloads/kustomize /usr/local/bin/kustomize
```

This used to work, but now results in the following errors:

```
5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3 does not exist. Create it first.
```

This is due to the following output from `kubectl version --output=json --client=true'

```
Client Version: v1.28.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
```

I cannot find this Kustomize version mentioned anywhere in any documentation. Is there a better way to install Kustomize and ensure compatibility between it and the kubectl client? I'm well aware that I can use Kustomize within Kubectl but I require the Kustomize cmd to set images through our pipeline.

Comment: You need to extract only the "5.0.4" part of the version.

Comment: But.. what's the point of downloading Kustomize separately if you only use the version bundled with kubectl?

Comment: I download Kustomize separately so that I can run various kustomize commands (like `kustomize edit set image`), which doesn't seem to be available via kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the dependency has [changed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/commit/90ca180ce06151e5bd8ff1e73756ed3d5e03f069):

```
-    sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v5 v5.0.1
-    sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml v0.14.1
+    sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v5 v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
+    sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml v0.14.3-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
```

So you'll need to change your `kubectl version` command to extract the version part. That said, you'll still run into an issue, as 5.0.4 does not exist as a release (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/tag/kustomize%2Fv5.0.4 gives a 404 page).

Given the suffix of the version, I would guess there is a missing tag/branch on [this commit](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/commit/6ce0bf390ce3dae580947a2b739da3306c675eef).

For what it's worth, I explicitly set the `kustomize` version to 5.0.3, and have not had any compatibility issues.

```
./install_kustomize.sh 5.0.3 /usr/local/bin
```